# Angular / UI-Router - How can I defer the load of a nested view, but not its parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a setup where I am toggling various views on a base level for multivariate testing purposes. I am using nested ui-view's to accomplish this without issue, however in one layout I'd like to defer the load of **only** the nested view until certain assets have loaded.

Currently I can only get it to defer both the child & parent, regardless of where I put the resolve. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? :/

app.js snippet

```
var wizardResolve = {
    assetLoader: ['$q', '$interval', function($q, $interval) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var interval = $interval(function() {
            if (apiAsset1 !== undefined && apiAsset2 !== undefined) {
                assetsLoaded = true;
                console.log(assetsLoaded);
                $interval.cancel(interval);
                defer.resolve();
            }
            console.log('spinning');
        }, 100);
    return defer.promise;
    }] 
};

//

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('wizard', {
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'components/wizard/wizard.html',
                },
                'main@wizard': {
                    templateUrl:     'components/wizard/base/core/main/main.html',
                    resolve: wizardResolve
                }
            }
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

// various api calls & callbacks...
```

multivariate-tests.directive.js snippet

```
angular.module('app.directives.mvTests', []).directive('mvTests', ['$rootScope','$window', '$location', '$state', function($rootScope,    $window, $location, $state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.view = 'wizard';  // forced view
            $state.go($scope.view);

            // -- Dynamic Paths ---------------
            $scope.headerPath = 'components/'+$scope.view+'/base/header/header.html';
            $scope.basePath = 'components/'+$scope.view+'/'+$scope.view+'.html';
            $scope.preFooterPath = 'components/'+$scope.view+'/base/pre-footer/pre-footer.html';
            $scope.footerPath = 'components/'+$scope.view+'/base/footer/footer.html';
    };
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="appCtrl" data-ngd-mv-tests>
<head> ... </head>
<body class="{{view}}">
    <div class="base" ui-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

wizard.html

```
<header role="banner" data-ng-include="headerPath"></header>
<main role="main" ui-view="main"></main>
<section class="pre-footer" data-ng-include="preFooterPath"></section>
<footer role="contentinfo" data-ng-include="footerPath"></footer>
```

Comment: Why are you not using the promises from the API that creates `apiAsset1` and `apiAsset2` in your resolver functions? It would be better to use promises instead of polling every 100ms.

Comment: @georgeawg that part of the code does what I need it to for now. I will eventually covert it.